# Difference between function(){ and function(e){

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between function(){ and function(e){? All over the web, i have seen in lot of places like,

`$('element').bind(function(){});`

and

`$('element').bind(function(e){});`.

But can anyone differentiate this clearly? So that i can understand that.

Comment: `e` here is the [`event`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is event object being passed to event function. You can find details of event object **[here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)**

- `$('element').bind(function(){})` does not provide the event object in it.
- `$('element').bind(function(e){})` provides event object could be used to determine the source that caused event by e.target, and provides method like stopPropagation() etc.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/yQGWa/1/)**

Here in live demo you wont be able to get the id of the td being click without event object.

Comment: Can you please give me an example

Answer (score 5):

I think the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) explains it pretty well.  Either is acceptable, but if you need access to the [event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) object, then you should pass that argument.  Otherwise, they are functionally the same.

Answer (score 0):

The second form allow you to use the [Event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) associated with the event.

Answer (score 0):

`e` is nothing but the event object passed to the handler from the calling code(jQuery).. however you can choose if you want to have it in your handler or not..

Basically it is available for use, but it is upto you to include it in your handler function or not.

Answer (score 0):

There's literally no difference, other than the fact you'll be able to access the "e" object in the second statement, which is the sender object (the element that has caused the function to be activated).

Comment: In jQuery, `this` is the "sender object", not `e`.

Comment: Apologies, as others have said, e is the event object.